# Angular: how to run a function in all the childs of a recursive component from another component?

Tags: angular

I normally communicate between components through a service. I create a variable in the service and when a component is created it binds itself to the variable in the service. I can then call everything from that component in other components through the service. The problem is that this won't work for a recursive component as the last child created will be the one that binds itself to the variable and only functions from this one child will be called.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjqrew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use rxjs observable for trigger function from service when your component is load

```
 private deviceName = new BehaviorSubject([]);
 device = this.devicesSource.asObservable();
```

In Component you can Subscribe the observable

```
this.myService.devicesSource.subscribe(ele=>{
   // Write your Code here
});
```